# How to differ whether the content text of UITextView is still under spelling or a real text?

Tags: ios, uitextview

As the following screen shot shows, for many languages, it needs a spelling to compose a target character, such as Chinese, Japanese, etc.

And for both statuses (the status that showing your original spelling input and the status that showing the composed characters), they are just the same as UITextView.text, and as it's not a real user selection, so the selection range also doesn't working for telling the "under spelling" text.

Is there any way to tell whether the current content text of UITextView is a composed characters or still under spelling?

Thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: Is turning off autocorrect for the `UITextView` acceptable?